Alien/human love scene.. Movie title?
I randomly remebered a couple scenes from a film that I believe, was released in the early 2000's and involved a murderous womanlike-alien being, that used some kind of swords or blades to kill people. 
The film was set on like a farm or ranch, that had lots of cows and sheep which i remember the plot was kind of based around. Perhaps to do with abduction or something..
Anyway. the only scene I remember is when one of the male protagonists is running away from the alien woman that is chasing after him, they head downstairs and when she catches upto him they stare at each other and form some kind of bond/relation and then end up having weird human/alien sex...
I know its not a lot to go on, it's a longshot and i was wondering if anyone knew the name of the film.

From what you've wrote movie sounds like species.

of course.. Species series... there is lots of it.. ;)

It's not an alien, per se, but the scene you describe is somewhat reminiscent of the movie Splice.
There's a creepy seduction scene in the barn where the lead couple are keeping their transgenic humanoid daughter-pet, that they created in secret in the lab where they work.  What could possibly go wrong?   Hilarity ensues.

This human and alien reminds of Species

From a second alien transmission, the scientists receive information about an alien DNA along with instructions on how to splice it with human DNA. A government team led by Xavier Fitch (Ben Kingsley) goes forward with the genetic experiment attempting to induce a female, because a female would have "more docile and controllable" traits. One of the hundred experimental ova produces a girl named Sil, who looks like a normal human but develops into a 12-year-old in 3 months
She is incredibly strong and intelligent with amazing regenerative powers. The scientists fear she may mate with human males and produce offspring that could eliminate the human race. Sil lacks inhibitions when it comes to killing people who get in her way and wants to produce offspring as soon as possible. She frequently morphs into her alien form, a bipedal creature with tentacles on her shoulders and back.

